# Can following be achieved using Docusign APIs?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to achieve some requirements via Docusign APIs. Would like to know if it's possible before I start the project.

I've used Docusign app for Salesforce earlier, but now I'm trying to achieve some functionalities through API calls

1. Ability for a Signed Document sent to a contact (by clicking on a button on contact record) to be attached to the Contact record it was sent from
2. Ability to write back to the record from a field tagged on the DocuSign envelope

Answer (score 0):

Vinay, this functionality is available using the DocuSign for Salesforce integration. If you would like to write it yourself using APIs, you can start by looking at our Apex toolkit here - https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/guides/apex-toolkit

Comment: Hey Inbar, Thanks for your reply. I guess apex-toolkit is available once you install Docusign for Salesforce managed package. Our requirement is to do the stuff without their AppExchange App. I'm trying to look for the same in their API documentation but unable to find the answer.